# How to save diagnostic plots from easystats to a file from a script

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, statistics, ggsave

A month ago, I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77876794/18255654) and I was able to solve it myself; however, after doing an update (`easystats::easystats_update()`), it no longer works. Therefore, my question remains the same: how can I save the diagnostics plot that is the output of `check_model(model)` from within a script?

When I do:

```
diagnost_fig = check_model(model)
ggsave(diagnostic_path, plot = diagnost_fig)
```

I get the error: `Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") :  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('check_model', 'see_check_model')"`

Then, when I plot it first:

```
diagnost_fig = plot(check_model(model))
ggsave(diagnostic_path, plot = diagnost_fig)
```

I now get the error: `Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") :  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "list"`

Is there a way to save the plot as I visualize it in

Here is a script that replicates this problem:

```
# Close all windows and clear all variables
rm(list = ls())
graphics.off()

# Load libraries
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(easystats)
library(see)

### Create example dataset
# Define the number of groups, time points, measures, and variables
n_groups = 2
time_points = c(1,5,9,12)
n_subjects = 8
n_variables = 2

# Create all combinations of groups, time points, and measures, and head data
data = expand.grid(group = paste0("Group",1:n_groups), time = time_points, subject = 1:n_subjects)
data = data[order(data$group, data$time, data$subject), ]
for (i in 1:n_variables) {data[[paste0("var", i)]] <- rnorm(nrow(data))}
head(data)

# Loop through variables
for (variable in paste0("var", 1:n_variables)) {
  # Create linear mixed model
  model = lmer(data[[variable]] ~ time*group + (1 + time | subject), data, control = lmerControl(optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))

  # Create paths to save boxplot and diagnostic plot
  boxplot_path = paste0("Example_Boxplot_", variable, ".png")
  diagnostic_path = paste0("Example_Diagnostic_", variable, ".png")  
  
  # Create boxplot
  variable_boxplot = ggplot(data, 
                          aes(x = time, 
                          y = !!sym(variable), 
                          group = interaction(time, group),
                          fill = group)) +
                    geom_boxplot(width = 3, 
                          position = position_dodge(width = 1.5),
                          alpha = 0.6)
  # Save boxplot
  ggsave(boxplot_path, plot = variable_boxplot)

  # PROBLEM: Create and try to save diagnostic plot

  # First try:
  check_model(model)
#   ggsave(diagnostic_path) # Just saves again the boxplot

  # Second try (prompts error):
  diagnost_fig = check_model(model)
#   ggsave(diagnostic_path, plot = diagnost_fig)
      # Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") :
      #   no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('check_model', 'see_check_model')"

  # Third try (prompts error):
  diagnost_fig = plot(check_model(model))
#   ggsave(diagnostic_path, plot = diagnost_fig)
      # Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
      #   no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "list"

}
```

Comment: I am guessing this generates not just one plot, but a few plots stitched together. `ggsave` no longer recognizes this as a ggplot object, but you can still just save manually using something like `png(diagnostic_path, width = 500, height = 500); plot(diagnost_fig); dev.off()`

Comment: Can confirm the solution from @Axeman works. You will need to have the `qqplotr` package installed to plot the confidence bands. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, it does work. Thank you both for the help. I will proceed to delete my older question.

Comment: Setting `panel = FALSE` should return the single ggplot-objects from `check_model()`. Else, a plot-composition from the _patchwork_ package is returned.